# How do solve Javascript blocking my asp.net buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am using preloader in my aspx page but my preloader blocks asp.net buttons,
how do I solve this?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.write('<script src="/dizin/dosyalar/bs/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="/dizin/dosyalar/bs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){$('#status').fadeOut();$('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');$('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});})
</script>
<div class="gnl-loading" id="preloader"></div>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ebulten" runat="server" OnClick="ebulten_OnClick" CssClass="btn btn-default footerbtn" ImageUrl="/dizin/site/img/index/btn.png" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript codes solved by getting inside the page

---

I got this error from jquery version

Check your old jquery codes and rewrite. Its will be work